# MQTT and SSL/TLS

Tags: ssl, openssl, mqtt, tls1.2, mosquitto

I registered for an account on a mqtt server provider.
They provide 3 ports:

- port: 1xxxx
- ssl port: 2xxxx
- websockets(TLS only): 3xxxx

I am publishing and receiving data from port 1xxx.

I would like to add encryption though. The mqtt server provider gives a "shared" subdomain but says:
If you want to use a custom domain for your instance you have to provide your own certificate to use with MQTT+TLS and Websockets. Certificates must be PEM encoded and the privte key unencrypted. Certs are only stored on your dedicated instance. When certs are installed you can point your domain as a CNAME to hairdresser.cloudmqtt.com.

I added a CNAME on my domain panel which I call it (mqtt.mydomain.com) and resolves to the above subdomain.

On my domain panel also I added ssl from letsenrypt(free) to my subdomain mqtt.mydomain.com(which points to mqtt server domain).

After adding the ssl I downloaded a zip file from the domain panel which contains 3 files:

1. mqtt.mydomain.com.ca
2. mqtt.mydomain.com.cert
3. mqtt.mydomain.com.key

[image: MQTT SSL Settings]

I paste the contents of ca file to CA chain, cert file to Certificate and key file to Private key

Saved everything and restarted instance(mqtt server).
Then I tried from my computer:

```
mosquitto_pub -h "mqtt.mydomain.com" -p 1xxxx -i test1 -u test1 -P pass1 -t mytopics/test1 -m "hi everyone" -d -c
```

works but since its port 1xxxx its not SSL.
Trying the ssl:

```
mosquitto_pub -h "mqtt.mydomain.com" -p 2xxxx -i test1 -u test1 -P pass1 -t mytopics/test1 -m "hi everyone" -d -c --cafile C:\Users\CT\Downloads\certs\mqtt.mydomain.com.ca
```

gives me error on cmd:
OpenSSL Error[0]: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
Error: A TLS error occurred.

Tried many different commands like passing cert file appart from ca and even key file(which is probably wrong i guess) and I am getting different errors on the server logs like:
OpenSSL Error: error:14094418:SSL routine

```
s:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca 
OpenSSL Error: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number 
Client connection from xx.xx.xx.xx failed: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number.
```

Comment: Make sure the that the CA file contains the full chain. LetsEncrypt provide 2 CA files. One with just the signing certificate and one with the full chain from the root CA to the actual signing cert.